# Jest mock of gRPC fails with manual definition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, grpc

I'm trying to test a React component, the store of the component is doing some gRPC communications, and thus requires the grpc node_module.  My test is importing grpc via chaining, because it imports the React component, which imports the store, which imports grpc.

This is fine, but the automock is failing:
`Error: The specified module could not be found. \\?\C:\Dev\Projects\Electron\PAT\client\app\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\grpc_node.node`

So I place a **mocks** folder adjacent to node_modules per Jest [Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/manual-mocks.html) and inside of it i create grpc.js:

```
const grpc = {};
export default grpc;
```

This gets me a little further, but:
`TypeError: grpc.makeGenericClientConstructor is not a function`

Understandable, so i try to change grpc.js to be:

```
const grpc = { makeGenericClientConstructor: () => { return; } };
```

But i continue to get the same error:
`TypeError: grpc.makeGenericClientConstructor is not a function`

I've tried using jest.setMock and jest.mock, neither seem to help.

Any ideas/suggestions/workarounds?

Comment: is jest evaluating it as an ES6 module? what happens if instead of using `export default grpc;` you used commonjs? `module.exports = grpc;`?

Comment: This fixed it thank you! Do you want to answer the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, by using `export default grps`, your module actually exports an es module:

```
{
   default: {
       makeGenericClientConstructor: ...
   }
}
```

You can confirm that to be true if you access `grpc.default.makeGenericClientConstructor` and it's there.

Using ES modules in your environment would work okay if you tell Jest to compile ES Module mocks to CommonJS (via babel), but if you don't do that, then you'll want to just export your mock as a CommonJS module using:

```
module.exports = grpc;
```